# Android Google Play Services Ads not showing

Tags: java, android, xml, google-play-services, ads

Hi All this is my first time posting here and my first time developing an app.

I am having trouble getting Google play services to work. I finally got all of my code to not error and the app to load on my phone. However, when it loads now, it is displaying a banner on top of my app with my app name.

```
package com.TylerGibson.MopeyMacaw;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import android.os.Bundle;

//import com.kilobolt.MopeyMacaw.R;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.kilobolt.ZombieBird.ZBGame;

public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;

        initialize(new ZBGame(), cfg);


    }
}
```

Below is my main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4445204025228818/4791459284" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.TylerGibson.MopeyMacaw"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity android:name="com.TylerGibson.MopeyMacaw.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

(cant post images) The Icon and "Mopey Macaw" you see up top is constantly displayed ever since i put in the code for ads/google-services. How can i fix this and get ads working? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have made some changes and switched around the below code to put it beneath Initialize statement. I now get ads but the ad is just displaying on a black screen, nothing else happens - cant see app.

    initialize(new ZBGame(), cfg);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

Answer (score 0):

AdView is case sensitive. Check your R.id.adView vs the id assigned in XML which is AdView.